# Convert eth_signTypedData_v4 signature to (v r s) format

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, signature

I have signature that I signed with "eth_signTypedData_v4"  method:

```
signature = "0xf9e46c67f179df6678f564cea1f8421039a58d9086819ba065e1ca87e76a06a018190f5e2b702b2ea613e45738e8d87a57480f4109c082b28e8da79e82e6d0321c"
```

But the function requires parameters v, r, s.
So, there is any ways to convert it?

I tried this, but unsuccessfully (got "execution reverted: Invalid v parameter"):

```
signature = "0xf9e46c67f179df6678f564cea1f8421039a58d9086819ba065e1ca87e76a06a018190f5e2b702b2ea613e45738e8d87a57480f4109c082b28e8da79e82e6d0321c"
signature = signature.substring(2)
r_data = "0x" + signature.substring(0, 64)
s_data = "0x" + signature.substring(64, 128)
rhema = parseInt(temporary.substring(128, 130), 16)
v_data = ethers.utils.hexlify(rhema + 1 * 2 + 8)         // 1 - chain id
```

Thank you all for the feedback! (if any)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ethers.utils.splitSignature()